# Visual Studio Community C# code formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, code-formatting, hotkeys

I am trying to format C# code of a WinForms .NET Core 7.0 project in Visual Studio Community:

[image: Screenshot of the poorly formatted code]

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<String, String> Dictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>
    {
        { "operation", "login" },
        { "phone", "123"},
        { "country","456"}      ,
        {          "otp", "789"},
        {"language","111" }
    };
}
```

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D</kbd>, removing the last brace in the code and putting it back.

The extra spaced are not getting removed. Can these be removed in whole code automatically using a command? If not, is there a plugin / extension that can help in code formatting?

Comment: Which command have you used?

Comment: Try removing the last brace in your code and putting it back.  If that doesn't work, you'll have to do it the old fashioned way.

Comment: I tried it, and also tried Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D

Comment: Which version of VS Community are you using? Sometimes changes to format haven't actually been made its purely visual, hover the mouse over the line or click into the space see if the formatting changes.

Comment: You could try to do CTRL+E+C

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.4.2

Comment: is your code open in a project? or just open as a "free" file

Comment: A WinForms .NET Core 7.0 project.

Comment: Hello, is it possible to take a look at the answer I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the shortcut key Ctrl+f.
2. Enter [^\S\r\n]{2,} in FIND
3. The value in the "replace" is empty
4. Select use regular expression(Alt+E)
5. Click the Replace All button(Alt+A)
6. Use the Auto Align shortcut (CTRL+K+D)

Comment: That's a good workaround, though a bit involved.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper works with VS Community and will reformat that case by either

- removing the `;` and re-entering it (format on typing)
- or reformatting the whole file via **Cleanup Code...** on the context menu for the C# file.

You'd have to pay for ReSharper, though, unless you're a student, working on an open-source project, or otherwise [qualify for the free license](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/#discounts).

Visual Studio Community (and probably Pro and Enterprise) doesn't seem to reformat dictionaries regardless of what you seem to do with a `.editorconfig` file or what you have set in **Tools | Options | Text Editor | C# | Code Style | Formatting | General**.

There may be other extensions that do this. Perhaps you could find one on the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/).